# Spring Boot SAML and AWS Cognito

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-cognito, saml

I have a working Cognito app client that utilizes user pool that is wired to use SAML. It accesses Azure AD as IdP. When I click "Launch Hosted UI" it properly redirects me to the login screen and upon authentication attempts to load my callback URL.
Now I want to wire this with a Spring Boot app.
I found [this example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/5.3.9.RELEASE/samples/boot/saml2login) developed by [Joe Grandja](https://github.com/jgrandja) that is using `spring-security-saml2-service-provider` to connect to a simple IdP.

The example is very compelling because all I really need to do is to provide correct configuration that in example provided like this:

```
spring:
  security:
    saml2:
      relyingparty:
        registration:
          simplesamlphp:
            signing.credentials:
              - private-key-location: "classpath:credentials/rp-private.key"
                certificate-location: "classpath:credentials/rp-certificate.crt"
            identityprovider:
              entity-id: https://simplesaml-for-spring-saml.apps.pcfone.io/saml2/idp/metadata.php
              verification.credentials:
                - certificate-location: "classpath:credentials/idp-certificate.crt"
              sso-url: https://simplesaml-for-spring-saml.apps.pcfone.io/saml2/idp/SSOService.php
```

However I'm lost at how to map information available to me from Cognito to these settings? For example values in `signing.credentials`?

Here's the list of settings I get from Cognito (all keys/names are bogus):

- Pool Id: us-west-2_1B1AHf00
- Pool ARN: arn:aws:cognito-idp:us-west-2:1234567898:userpool/us-west-2_1B1AHf00
- Domain: https://blah-foo.auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com
- App client: blahfoo-client
- App client ID: 1b1l1a2f8oo83456c
- Callback URL: http://localhost:8080
- Login URL: https://blah-foo.auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com/login?client_id=1b1l1a2f8oo83456c&response_type=code&scope=email+openid&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080

I also have a SAML-formatted file I got back from IdP but that is already plugged into Cognito so why would I put anything from it into the app configuration?

I wonder if part of `spring-security-saml2-service-provider` is to assemble that login URL and if I can get away with less settings that are given in the example?

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `signing.credentials` section is if your app needs to sign things like [an AuthnRequest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-saml2login-sp-initiated-factory). They are credentials that you own.

The items under `identityprovider` are things that Cognito would provide.

For Spring Boot 2.4+, if Cognito supports a SAML metadata endpoint, then [you can provide that](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/blob/5.5.0/servlet/spring-boot/java/saml2-login/src/main/resources/application.yml) and Spring Security will discover the rest:

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    saml2:
      relyingparty:
        registration:
          simplesamlphp:
            identityprovider:
              metadata-uri: classpath:cognito/metadata/file/location
```

Or, for earlier versions, you can [use `RelyingPartyRegistrations`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-saml2login-sansboot):

```java
@Bean
RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository registrations() {
    String location = "classpath:cognito/metadata/file/location";
    RelyingPartyRegistration registration = 
        RelyingPartyRegistrations.fromMetadataLocation(location)
            .build();
    return new InMemoryRelyingPartyRegistration(registration);
}
```

That said, the information that you've posted about Cognito's authentication endpoint appears OAuth-based, especially the Login URL. You may instead consider [configuring your app for OAuth 2.0](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2login) and pointing at Cognito's OAuth endpoint.

Comment: Thanks @jzheaux ! It appears that even Cognito give you ability to select between various IoPs including SAML what is exposes to the actual client is OAuth-based. Could this be the case?

Comment: That was my experience with Cognito in the past, yes. Cognito can federate authentication from several upstream SAML providers and then "output" OAuth to you. In that case, you'd configure your app for OAuth, not SAML.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting the solution as a separate answer however credit and accepted answer go to @jzheaux

Basically the comment section provides the much needed hint: Even if you are wiring SAML-based Identity provider you will wire up Cognito using OAuth information given to you in the AWS console for `User Pool`

In my specific case the `application.yaml` then looks like this:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          cognito:
            client-id: 1ab2cd34efghi5jk6klmno7p8
            client-secret: *********
            scope: openid
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/cognito
            clientName: foobar-sandbox
        provider:
          cognito:
            issuerUri: https://cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/us-west-2_abCDeFGHI
            user-name-attribute: cognito:username
```

`client-secret` is found in `General settings -> App clients -> Show Details`